# C# Saving Textbox to Array to Print out to Second Textbox ( A chat client )

Tags: c#, arrays, list, textbox, chat

I am having trouble getting my chat application working correctly. I have 2 textbox's, 1 to type what you would like to send, and another to display the conversation. For now I am trying to display what the user enters in the typeBox In the displaybox. I imagine I need an array or list of type string and add the entered text to it each time the button is pressed, then print the array/list to the displaybox. I have been trying a few approaches but I cant quite get it working correctly.

Could anyone shed some light on what approach to take ?

**EDIT:**

This is the code which I have so far. It is print out the array but without a line break and It fails to clear the display box each time, so I am getting duplicated of the same messages appearing.

```
    string ArrayData = string.Empty;
    ArrayList listData = new ArrayList();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listData.Add(entryBox.Text);

        foreach (string textItem in listData)
        {

            ArrayData = "You >> " +ArrayData + textItem + "\n";

        }
        entryBox.Focus();
        displayBox.Text = "";
        displayBox.Refresh();
        this.displayBox.Text = ArrayData;
        entryBox.Text = "";

    }
```

This is probably obvious what Is wrong here but Ive been looking at it so long I cant see it.

Cheers,

: Dan

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly? Do you need an idea how to print the array/list to the displaybox? Adding the data to the array/list? And what have you tried to achieve this? Some code examples would be helpful

Comment: here is a simple chat tutorial in c#: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33396-basic-clientserver-chat-application-in-c%23/

Comment: I have updated the post with some of my code.

Comment: `ArrayData = "You >> " +ArrayData + textItem + "\n";` this link looks funny shouldn't it be `ArrayData = ArrayData+"You >> " + textItem + "\n";` Add a `ArrayData ="";` before the foreach loop as well.

Comment: Thank you anselm, I knew I was going wrong there somewhere. This has solved the issuse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wouldn't appending the string in the inputbox with `\n` to the string in the display box solve your problem? you do not need to save each line in an array or arraylist

Pseudocode

```
onclick
displaybox.text = displaybox.text + inputbox.text +"\n"
```

Comment: "\n" does not seem to be working for me. It just displays an unknown character rather than add a linebreak.

Comment: First take a quick look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx to learn about the AppendText() method and then at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx to find a nice clean solution for your line break problem. Cheers!

Comment: Ah yes. `\r\n` is Giving me my line break. Now I just have to figure out why I am getting the duplicates. I must be saving to the array wrong. Eg: If I enter `1` I get `1`. if I then Enter `2` I get `112`

Comment: look at my comment above your text is wrong use `ArrayData = ArrayData+"You >> " + textItem + "\n";` instead

Comment: Just to expand on this issue. I would like the return key to also execute the same code as clicking the button.

I have the following code:

`private void entryBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
            {
                entryBox.Text = "";
                button1.PerformClick();

            }
        }`

This is printing everything except the message entered out to the displayBox. 
Eg. Im getting "You >>" and a line break.

Any insight as to where im going wrong in this case ?

: Dan

Comment: `entryBox.Text = "";`  is resetting the text

Comment: Hmm, it seems that removing `entryBox.text = ""` helped. I am now seeing the entered text being displayed but It is after a linebreak :/.

Comment: try calling `button1_Click(null,null);`

Comment: It turns out that I had to call `SendKeys.Send("\b");` to remove the linebreak that the return key created.